# Get values of multidimensional Array (Node.js / JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Hey I got this object inside *polygons.js*:

```
var polygons = [
  {
    "_id" : "12345",
    "geometry" : {
       "coordinates" : [[
           [9.123553, 48.71568],
           [ 9.119548, 48.71526 ]
       ]]
    }
  },
  {
    "_id" : "67890",
    "geometry" : {
       "coordinates" : [[
           [ 9.090445, 48.715736 ],
           [ 9.089583, 48.715687 ]
       ]]
    }
  }
]
```

When I call `console.log(polygons[1].geometry);` I only get this result instead of the numbers:

```
{ 
  coordinates: 
   [ [ [Array],
       [Array] 
    ] ]
}
```

Can You help me out? Thanks in regard.

Comment: sorry the headline is wrong because first I wanted to ask a question about how to loop through this array. Sorry !

Comment: `When I call console.log(polygons[1].geometry)` that would return an array, which holds another array which contains two arrays with values.

Comment: edited headline of my question. Sorry again!

Comment: @vlaz thanks, I think I solved this tiny issue !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the coordinates:

```
 var firstCoords = polygons[0].geometry.coordinates[0][0]; //[9.123553, 48.71568]
 var secondCoords = polygons[0].geometry.coordinates[0][1]; //[ 9.119548, 48.71526 ]
```

If you want to loop through them:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < polygons[0].geometry.coordinates[0].length; i++){
     //do whatever you want with the coordinates
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the object to a string with `JSON.stringify()`.

Anyway, here it's working in both cases:

```js
var polygons = [
  {
    "_id" : "12345",
    "geometry" : {
       "coordinates" : [[
           [9.123553, 48.71568],
           [ 9.119548, 48.71526 ]
       ]]
    }
  },
  {
    "_id" : "67890",
    "geometry" : {
       "coordinates" : [[
           [ 9.090445, 48.715736 ],
           [ 9.089583, 48.715687 ]
       ]]
    }
  }
]

console.log(polygons[1].geometry);
console.log(JSON.stringify(polygons[1].geometry));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print the coordinates of each polygon, something like this might be helpful:

```js
var polygons = [{
    "_id": "12345",
    "geometry": {
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [9.123553, 48.71568],
          [9.119548, 48.71526]
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "67890",
    "geometry": {
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [9.090445, 48.715736],
          [9.089583, 48.715687]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
];

function printCoordinates(polygon) {

  // Iterate over the coordinate groups and print out each coordinate in the polygo
  polygon.geometry.coordinates.map(coordinateGroup => {
    coordinateGroup.map(coordinatePair => {
      console.log(`${coordinatePair[0]}, ${coordinatePair[1]}`)
    });
  });
}

printCoordinates(polygons[0]);
printCoordinates(polygons[1]);
```

Comment: thank you for this solution. The result should be an array like this:

`[
  { 
    "_id" : "12345",
    "coordinates" : [[
      [9.123553, 48.71568],
      [ 9.119548, 48.71526 ]  
    ]]
  },
  { 
    "_id" : "67890",
    "coordinates" : [[
      [ 9.090445, 48.715736 ],
      [ 9.089583, 48.715687 ]  
    ]]
  }
]`

Answer (score -1):

Change `console.log(polygons[1].geometry);` to this `console.log(JSON.stringify(polygons[1].geometry, null, 4));`

should do the trick.

Comment: That...converts the object into JSON instead of giving any values back.

Comment: Yes it turns the object and all its values into a string so that console.log() can print the contents of the entire object rather than the results of the toString() method on the arrays.

Comment: try running it... not only does it work but it prints it out in a clean and readable format

Comment: I know what this does. It still doesn't solve the problem posted - it isn't "how do I format this for display" but "how do I get the values from array". The latter is always associated with *using* said values in your application, not only being able to see them and note them down.

Comment: If you just look at the heading of the post then yes But if you read the contents of the post then you will see the person asks about a specific command (console.log) with a specific result that is not the result they are specifically looking for. "When I call console.log(polygons[1].geometry); I only get this result instead of the numbers" followed by their sample output showing the printed object with [Array] "instead of numbers". The solution I provided would give them a result with numbers where they are seeing [Array], which was the problem they were showing.

Comment: And your solution does NOT give the numbers. It prints an entire JSON which is, by definition, not "numbers". So your solution fails to satisfy that interpretation, either.

Comment: the result in question is a representation of the data object printed as a string (the result is now defined as a string that may contain numbers). The poster described getting “only” a specific result which is, by definition, a result that is valid in type but partial in quantity/quality. What it lacks in quantity/quality is then immediately defined as numbers. Since numbers are something the result is capable of being comprised of my solution satisfies this.

Comment: I think the mistake you made was assuming Get means simply to access. When it really means to retrieve what is being requested, which requires but is not limited to access.

Comment: In this case, what is being requested, is a data object represented as a string with access to the values (which happen to be numbers) of a multidimensional array.